# I want to send a connect-log message to discord through discord bot by following a file in tailer module

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Here's my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands
import tailer
import pyrcon
import geocoder
import time


Prefix = "-"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=Prefix, case_insensitive = True, intents = discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(bot.user)
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.dnd)
    for line in tailer.follow(open("/data/dm/main/connectlog.log")):
        Name = line.split('%')[1]
        IP = line.split('%')[3]
        ip_address = geocoder.ip(IP)
        country = ip_address.country
        state = ip_address.state
        city = ip_address.city
        time.sleep(4)
        if "\"connect" in line:
            embed = discord.Embed(title = f"Player {Name} connected to SS-DM server", description=f"IP : {IP}\nCountry : {country}\nState/Province : {state}\n City : {city}", color=0x00FF00)
            channel = bot.get_channel(ID)
            await channel.send(embed = embed)
       
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

So when I run my above code it shows the following error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/discord/client.py", line 828, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 633, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 600, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1896, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/discord/client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/dm/main/codwatcher1.py", line 65, in on_ready
    for line in tailer.follow(open("/data/dm/main/connectlog.log")):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tailer/__init__.py", line 182, in follow
    time.sleep(delay)
```

Basically I am trying to follow a file through tailer module of python and send it to discord. I tried everything but in vain, so I hope you guys can help me figure this out.

Its my gameserver log. To see who connected to my server..

Comment: There's some important info missing from your traceback, can you include the whole thing? Also, do not make **any** API requests in `on_ready`. This includes presence, but also sending messages to channels. (Changing presence is unnecessary anyways - you can just pass it to your `Bot`'s `__init__()` call)

Comment: So how would I automate the discord bot then. Like how would I give it a task to see the connect logs?

Comment: With `Tasks`: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html

Comment: If all you're doing is sending a message to a channel, you can also use a `Webhook` instead of a bot.

Comment: Ok I'll use the webhook then. Thanks.